# How to restrict access to DetailView depending on user permission AND MODEL ATTRIBUTE VALUE?

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to restrict access to some detail article pages that have an attribute `is_private=True` . They can be displayed in article list, but only users who have a permission `view_private_articles` must be able to access article DetailView.

models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
    )
    is_private = models.BooleanField(
    default=False,
    )
```

views.py:

```
class ArticleListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'article_objects_list'
    login_url = 'login'

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("view_private_articles", "Can view private articles"),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


class  ArticleDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        PermissionRequiredMixin,
        DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    permission_required = 'view_private_articles'
```

Problem is, as you could notice, that approach, described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) can only restrict users who don't have `view_private_articles` permission to view ALL ARTICLES (not only with `is_private=True` attribute).

**So how to restrict that users to view only articles with attribute `is_private=True`?**

*UPDATE01
I've tried to add UserPassesTestMixin with no result:*

```
class  ArticleDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        PermissionRequiredMixin,
        UserPassesTestMixin,
        DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    permission_required = 'view_private_articles'

        def test_func(self):
        article_obj = self.get_object()
        user_obj = self.request.user
        if article_obj.is_private is True and user_obj.has_perms("view_private_articles"):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I am still get 403 forbidden if my user hasn't `view_private_articles` permission regardless of whether there is an attribute `is_private` or not because of PermissionRequiredMixin. But if i delete PermissionRequiredMixin, my user without `view_private_articles` permission can access to detail article. Obviously method i wrote is crap, but how to get it right?

**UPDATE02 it's works like that:**

```
class  ArticleDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        UserPassesTestMixin,
        DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    permission_required = 'view_private_articles'

        def test_func(self):
        article_obj = self.get_object()
        user_obj = self.request.user
        if article_obj.is_private is True and user_obj.has_perm("blog.view_private_articles"):
            return True
        return False
```

where blog - name of the app containing model . Thank to @dirkgroten!

**UPDATE03 also it can be done by view method `dispatch` overriding:**

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class  ArticleDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_obj = self.request.user
        if not user_obj.has_perm("blog.view_private_articles"):
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Override the `get_queryset()` method on the list view and add the filter on the queryset depending on whether or not the user is allowed. For the detail view, you'll need to use the `UserPassesTestMixin` where you can check for the particular article whether the user is allowed or not.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you for participating
Firsly i've insterested in Detailview.
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) shown how to work with user attributes (return self.request.user.email.endswith('@example.com')
) but there is no example how to operate with model instance attributes. Could you give an example please?

Comment: `self.get_object()` will give your the article object in a `DetailView` so you can do `return self.get_object().is_private` for your test function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably also don't want to show all articles in your `ListView`. So there are two different approaches for the `ListView` and the `DetailView`.

For the `ListView` you should override `get_queryset()`. Here you can send back different lists depending on the user:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    qs = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_staff:
        return qs
    if self.request.user.has_perm("view_private_articles"):
        return qs.filter(is_private=True)
    return qs.none()
```

For the `DetailView`, add a `UserPassesTestMixin` to your view and use `get_object()` to verify the user is allowed to view the specific object:

```
 def test_func(self):
     return self.request.user.may_view(self.get_object())  # assuming you write a `may_view(article)` method on a `User` model.
```

Comment: i didn't understood how my `ArticleDetailView` should look. Like that?
`
class  ArticleDetailView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        PermissionRequiredMixin,
        DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'article_object'
    template_name = 'detail/article_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'
    permission_required = 'view_private_articles'
    def test_func(self):
        return self.user.may_view(self.get_object())` ?
I get an error: "Unresolved attribute reference 'user' for class  ArticleDetailView"

Comment: obviously that should be self.request.user. but i'm just giving you a direction, you can't just literally copy&past my code (you probably don't have `may_view()` defined).

Comment: could you please show a `may_view(article)` method on a `User` model ?
is it possible to use the `.has_perm("view_private_articles")` method here?

Comment: yes, you can also just do it in the `test_func()` itself. e.g. `self.request.user.has_perm('view_private_articles') and self.get_object().is_private`. Whatever code you need to check that this object may be viewed by this user. I like to keep this logic in the models, where it belongs.

Comment: i've tried to use it but failed :( (i've updated question)

Comment: Read my answer: "add `UserPassesTestMixin` to your view"

Comment: i did, just didn't transfer it here
now i've edited a question. it's doesn't work like that