# Trying to restrict items to a specific user in a Django Class Based View query set

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class AccountManager(models.Model):
    account_manager = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.account_manager)

class Client(models.Model):
    account_manager = models.ForeignKey(AccountManager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account_manager_clients')
    client = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client

class Contract(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='client_contracts')
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site_name
```

I can restrict the clients to the specific account managers by using the following view

```
class ClientListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Client
    template_name = "clients/list.html"

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(account_manager__account_manager=self.request.user)
        )
```

However I can't seem to restrict the contracts to the account manager with the following view:

```
class AMContractDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Contract
    template_name = 'contracts/am_contract_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(client__account_manager=self.request.user.id)
        )
```

This allows account managers to see all the clients not just their own.
I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong but have got a bit lost!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not you just use `ListView` for the `AMContractDetailView` as you are trying to get the list of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to totally understand what's the source of the problem here, but I recommend you to opt for another approach, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509428/how-to-restrict-access-to-detailview-depending-on-user-permission-and-model-attr#answer-57509713) in another StackOverflow question: your class-based view `AMContractDetailView` could inherit from `UserPassesTestMixin` (cf. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)) to check whether or not the user should be able to see that page.

Otherwise, try to override another method of `DetailView`, for instance `get` (all available methods are listed [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)).

By the way, your views `ClientListView` and `AMContractDetailView` have 2 parent methods. To resolve a potential ambiguity when calling `super`, I think you should explicitly pass arguments to the function, e.g. `super(DetailView, self)`.

Comment: Many thanks for this. In the end I changed the model structure and solved the problem. However your last point was very valid